# Javascript for attribute assign not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with different text values in it cells, and I want to assign different bgcolors to each cell, depending on their text.

Here's the code I've made -

```
var subjects = ["Geography", "English", "Biology", "Math", "Sanskrit", "Physics", "Chemistry", "History"];
        var colors = ["#DEF862", "#62F87F", "#62E2F8", "#7F62F8", "#F662F8", "#F8627A", "#F87062", "#E09484"];
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
            if (subjects.includes(elems[i].textContent) == true){
                let ind = subjects.indexOf(elems[i].textContent);
                elems[ind].setAttribute("bgcolor", colors[ind]);
            }
        }
```

The length of elems is 25, and the loop goes through all of them. However, it only works for the first 10, after which is doesn't do anything.

Why is this happeing?

Comment: Please post the relavent html aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `bgcolor` attribute on HTML elements (the global attributes are [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes)), so setting it has no effect.

If you want to use inline styling (I wouldn't, I'd suggest using a class), you can do it by using the element's [`CSSStyleDeclaration` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) via its [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

```
elems[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[ind];
```

Note also that I've changed `ind` to `i`, since [as charlietfl points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787814/157247), `ind` is the index in `subjects`, not `elems`.

Also, there's no point in calling `includes` and then turning around and calling `indexOf`, just call `indexOf`, it'll give you `-1` in the case where the text isn't found:

```js
var subjects = ["Geography", "English", "Biology", "Math", "Sanskrit", "Physics", "Chemistry", "History"];
var colors = ["#DEF862", "#62F87F", "#62E2F8", "#7F62F8", "#F662F8", "#F8627A", "#F87062", "#E09484"];
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
    const ind = subjects.indexOf(elems[i].textContent);
    if (ind !== -1) {
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[ind]);
    }
}
```

---

Side note: If you are ever going to run the code again with a different input string, you probably want to remove the background from elements that no longer match, which is another reason for using a class rather than inline styling (you don't have to worry about restoring any previous custom value that may have been there before you changed it; you just remove the class).

I'd also use

- An object array rather than parallel arrays
- `const` and `let` rather than `var` (there's really no place for `var` in modern JavaScript code)
- `for-of` rather than a `for` loop

...but it's a matter of style.

For what it's worth, here's my take:

```js
const highlighting = [
    {subject: "Geography", color: "#DEF862"},
    {subject: "English", color: "#62F87F"},
    {subject: "Biology", color: "#62E2F8"},
    // ...
];
const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (const elem of elems) {
    const text = elem.textContent;
    const highlight = highlighting.find(({subject}) => subject === text);
    if (highlight) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = highlight.color;
    } else {                                // *** If needed
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "";    // ***
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const highlighting = [
    {subject: "Geography", color: "#DEF862"},
    {subject: "English", color: "#62F87F"},
    {subject: "Biology", color: "#62E2F8"},
    // ...
];
const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (const elem of elems) {
    const text = elem.textContent;
    const highlight = highlighting.find(({subject}) => subject === text);
    if (highlight) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = highlight.color;
    } else {                                // *** If needed
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "";    // ***
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <td>Geography</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>Biology</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Or with a `data-*` attribute instead:

```js
const subjects = ["Geography", "English", "Biology", "Math", "Sanskrit", "Physics", "Chemistry", "History"];
const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (const elem of elems) {
    if (subjects.includes(elem.textContent)) {
        elem.setAttribute("data-subject", elem.textContent);
    } else {
        elem.removeAttribute("data-subject");
    }
}
```

with this CSS

```css
[data-subject=Geography] {
    background-color: #DEF862;
}
[data-subject=English] {
    background-color: #62F87F;
}
[data-subject=Biology] {
    background-color: #62E2F8;
}
/* ... * /
```

Live Example:

```js
const subjects = ["Geography", "English", "Biology", "Math", "Sanskrit", "Physics", "Chemistry", "History"];
const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (const elem of elems) {
    if (subjects.includes(elem.textContent)) {
        elem.setAttribute("data-subject", elem.textContent);
    } else {
        elem.removeAttribute("data-subject");
    }
}
```

```css
[data-subject=Geography] {
    background-color: #DEF862;
}
[data-subject=English] {
    background-color: #62F87F;
}
[data-subject=Biology] {
    background-color: #62E2F8;
}
/* ... * /
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <td>Geography</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>Biology</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic logic problem is you should use `elems[i]` instead of `elems[ind]` which is constrained by the length and indexing of the string  arrays